Parsing simple text with tesseract
I am embarking on a project in OCR and I thought the simplest task to start would be to parse a block of digits so I created a simple block of digits which I wanted to parse.
However, I am struggling to reliably parse this simple image (see below). The obvious mistake that I can spot easily is that '0' gets classified as an '8'.
The image is high quality - I've pasted a section of a larger image I have. I don't understand if I am doing something incorrectly or if this is really the limit of tesseract. Below is my code:
def read_gray(file):
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return gray

config = '-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789 --psm 6'
text_raw = pytesseract.image_to_string(read_gray('example.png'), config=config)

What am I doing wrong? Is it worth it to slice this image into small squares each containing a single digit? Can this be automated?
I feel like I have missed something and I'm making things more complicated.


If the source resolution of your image is less than 300 DPI, try scaling it up first and see if that improves results.
